# MYsqli Error in selecting, works in workbench not in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error after passing a variable containing the query inside the FROM(). The query works on workbench but not on php.

This is the error:

```
["Error in Selecting ","Error in Selecting You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')cnt' at line 1 SELECT SUM(counting) FROM()cnt"]
```

And the variable that generates the error:

```
$summ = "SELECT SUM(count) FROM($resFinalQuery)cnt";
```

$resFinalQuery content:

```
(SELECT 'schema1' as 'Schema', MIN(concat(DATEIN, ' ', HOURIN)) as DATEHOUR, COUNT(*) as counting FROM schema1.calls WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1)
   UNION ALL
(SELECT 'schema2' as 'Schema', MIN(concat(DATEIN, ' ', HOURIN)) as DATEHOUR, COUNT(*) as counting FROM schema2.calls WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1)
```

EDIT: I solved this thank you, i had done the check before but forgot to put my code inside the if brackets.

Comment: Echo your query. The syntax is incorrect. I have no idea what `($resFinalQuery)cnt` is supposed to be, but you're missing at least one space

Comment: I would guess you do not set `$resFinalQuery` in the right scope. For example, you may be setting it in a PHP function, so it is lost when that function returns. Or you may be setting it in a previous PHP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message shows

> SELECT SUM(counting) FROM()cnt

So `$resFinalQuer` is empty

Assumeing that $resFinalQuer is a subquery the query muat look like

```
SELECT SUM(count) FROM ($resFinalQuery) cnt
```

which results in

```
SELECT SUM(count) FROM ((SELECT 'schema1' as 'Schema', MIN(concat(DATEIN, ' ', HOURIN)) as DATEHOUR, COUNT(*) as counting FROM schema1.calls WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1)
   UNION ALL
(SELECT 'schema2' as 'Schema', MIN(concat(DATEIN, ' ', HOURIN)) as DATEHOUR, COUNT(*) as counting FROM schema2.calls WHERE STATE = 17 AND LEVEL = 1)) cnt
```